# T-SQL query fails when data is lowercase because database holds it in capitalization

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In my database all the data is capitalized, for example Last Name (`BRIERTON`). When I run my query in lowercase like (`brierton`), it will not find it. Is it possible to put something in the query to search both capital or lowercase so that it does not think it does not exist for `[pye_nlast] AS "Name Last"`?

```
SELECT 
    [pye_nlast] AS "Name Last",
    [pye_nfirst] AS "Name First",
    [EmployeeTC_No] AS "Employee TC #",
    [EmploymentType] AS "Employment Type",
    [RetentionCode] AS "GS #"
FROM 
    [OnBaseWorking].[dbo].[Employees]
WHERE
    EmployeeTC_No != 'Not Assigned'
    AND pye_nlast = '@primary'
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Literal strings do need to be quoted, but parameter names should not be quoted. The current search is looking for something literally named `@primary`, which of course does not exist. (Unless your query is not actually using proper parameterization, but textually replacing values, which is a bad idea indeed.)

Comment: The vast majority of databases uses a case-insensitive collation for all columns, as that is the server default if you don't change anything during installation. It would be quite unusual/undesirable to have a database where comparisons were really case sensitive for things like human names, so verify that you really have the problem you're having, and if you do, whether the column should not be using a case-insensitive collation instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just force lower case:

```
lower(pye_nlast) = lower(@primary)
```

I'm not sure why you are enclosing `@primary` in single quotes.  That is suspicious.

Or, if the data really is all in upper case:

```
pye_nlast = upper(@primary)
```

Comment: @DavidBrierton . . . You can use `upper()` instead of `lower()`.

Comment: Note of caution... applying LOWER() or UPPER() to the table column will prevent any possibly of a SEEK operation on that column. If you know that the table data is all UPPER, then only apply the UPPER() function to the @parameter value.